# Why are window functions used when calculating spectral estimates, really?

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, window-functions, window

Having just read the rather long article on Wikipedia about [window functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function), I still do not see the mathematical point in using window functions when calculating spectral estimates (using e.g. Welch's method).

For example,

> The Fourier transform of the function cos ωt is zero, except at frequency ±ω. However, many other functions and waveforms do not have convenient closed form transforms

what is this supposed to mean? I doubt any sampled and digitized signal has a convenient closed form transform anymore.

Comment: One main reason is control of [spectral leakage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_leakage).

Comment: windows also is using to analyse short segments of signals which is assumed to be stationary,for example STFT use windows for non stationary signals

Answer (score 3):

You are right that no real-world signal will have a "convenient closed form" transform. I also find the quoted sentence misleading, and in my opinion it does not motivate the use of windowing. From your question I believe that you do not actually ask about the pros and cons of different window functions, but if I understand you correctly you ask yourself why people cut signals into pieces anyway if they want to analyze their spectrum. The reason is that many real-world signals are simply too long and/or their length is not known. So you don't want to wait till the signal is 'complete', and you also don't want the complexity of processing such a long signal. So you do block-processing, which reduces computational complexity and gives you quickly a spectral estimate. When you cut the signal into blocks you have many parameters that will influence the result of the spectral estimate: the block length, the type of window, the overlap between blocks, etc. This is a complex topic but you'll find a lot of literature about it. If you have access to Oppenheim and Schafer's *Discrete-time Signal Processing* I would recommend the chapter on *Fourier Analysis of Signals Using the Discrete Fourier Transform*. It has a lot of valuable information about block processing and windowing.

Answer (score 2):

The DFT has a built-in implicit rectangular window.  You're taking a chunk of a stream of input data and transforming it.  But by just slicing it out of the input, you leave very sharp edges on it.  This gives the overall transform a rectangular shape, which after transforming gives you a sinc envelope in the frequency domain (DFT(rect) = sinc).  Sincs have very poor sidelobe characteristics (-13dB first sidelobe).  So you can get a lot of energy leaking back into your passband that you didn't want.  Windowing the data before transforming smoothes out those sharp edges and dramatically reduces the sidelobes.